# Some of Users of an Android App cannot Load AdMob ADs

Tags: android, admob, adsense-api, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am asking for a best practice or implementation.

My app's core function providing service for a long time (2 to 4 hours). The users have some active time and when they use the service, the active time is consumed. The user can restore the active time by watching a rewarded video AD of AdMob.

The problem is, some of the users (less than 3%) cannot see any ADs on their device. I got many complaints that they cannot load the ADs. Most of the users not seeing ADs are using an AD-blocker, but some are under "AD-no fill" status (error code 3). In this case, it seems my app generates too many AD-requests (by users clicking "watch AD"), so AdMob cannot always fill the ADs. My app lets an user to watch ADs less than 10 times a day.

I have some plans and would like to know which one is better:

1) Include another AD-provider. When the AD of AdMob is not filled, my app loads another AD.
Drawback: 2x code complexity and 2x maintenance effort.

2) When the real AD is not filled, load an test-AD of AdMob.
Drawback: no money

3) When an AD is not filled, load another AD unit of AdMob.
Drawback: I am not sure if this works. The AdMob should have determined the user (not AD-unit) is not getting an AD on this request, so generating another request doesn't help. And based on this [AdMob loading multiple rewarded videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968622/admob-loading-multiple-rewarded-videos) discussion, it is not allowed to load multiple AD-units.

4) The others I didn't come up with.

5) Is 10 times of watching rewarded-AD too many?

Comment: [Admob banner ad not loading in android P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361457/admob-ad-stopped-working-in-android-pie-api28) In this thread, clear the data/cache of **Google Play services** seems resolve the problem. I am waiting for more users' feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although in the [Admob banner ad not loading in android P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361457/admob-ad-stopped-working-in-android-pie-api28) thread, the workaround on the user end works (based on the users' feedback of my app), I still patched the app due to the issue of this thread.

My final approach is handling errors of **errorCode == 0** or **3**.
Based on the [AdMob document](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads), there are 4 errors of **onRewardedAdFailedToLoad()** method:

**errorCode == 0: ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR** - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

**errorCode == 1: ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST** - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

**errorCode == 2: ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR** - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.

**errorCode == 3: ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL** - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

**Case 1** only happens by a careless developer. It should not happen. It is not user trigger-able.

**Case 2** occurs when a user uses an AD-blocker or network connection is down. It is user trigger-able.

**Case 0** and **case 3** are not controllable by users nor developers.

My code can deal with the errors in **case 0** and **3**. This code ignore the **errorCode == 2** to prevent users using AD-blocker or turning off the network to get rewards. From now on most of the users are happy.

Note: the code

> (errorCode == 2 && BuildConfig.DEBUG)

is for testing purpose. I can turn off the network to trigger the **errorCode == 2** to see if this approach works properly.

Here is all my code:

```java
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {  // ad should be loaded but not
        Log.i(TAG, "Ad: onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(): " + errorCode);
    }
    adButton.setEnabled(false);
    adButton.setText(getString(R.string.text_ad_unavailable, errorCode));

    if (errorCode == 0 || errorCode == 3 || (errorCode == 2 && BuildConfig.DEBUG)) {
        noAdButton.setEnabled(true);  // give 1/4 reward of watching AD
        noAdButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```